# Hinge loss vs categorical_hinge loss in Keras

Tags: neural-networks, multi-class

I was working on a project where I implemented a CNN model with hinge loss in Keras. The task is a multiclass classification where I try to classify sensor measurements into 6 classes. I'm aware that in Keras, for non binary classification usually the 'categorical_hinge" loss is utilized, but in my case both  'hinge and squared_hinge' losses  are working fine and the model is trained successfully, although we know that they are designed for binary classification only. What am I missing ?
Here is my code, where I have implemented a  simple typical architecture of CNN.

```
i = Input(shape=(120, 3))
x = Conv1D(32, kernel_size= 3, strides = 2, activation='relu')(i)
x = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size= 3, strides = 2, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Flatten()(x)  
x = Dense(120, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(6 ,activation='linear')(x)
model = Model(i, x)
model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = "squared_hinge", metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),  epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Here you can see the result of training process that has been successfully done :

```
Epoch 1/10
236/236 [==============================] - 4s 11ms/step - loss: 0.2135 - accuracy: 0.4413 - val_loss: 0.1346 - val_accuracy: 0.5941
Epoch 2/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 0.1153 - accuracy: 0.6764 - val_loss: 0.1058 - val_accuracy: 0.7045
Epoch 3/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0863 - accuracy: 0.7856 - val_loss: 0.0894 - val_accuracy: 0.7703
Epoch 4/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0656 - accuracy: 0.8449 - val_loss: 0.0853 - val_accuracy: 0.7766
Epoch 5/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0523 - accuracy: 0.8837 - val_loss: 0.0802 - val_accuracy: 0.8064
Epoch 6/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0404 - accuracy: 0.9201 - val_loss: 0.0755 - val_accuracy: 0.8208
Epoch 7/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0323 - accuracy: 0.9407 - val_loss: 0.0751 - val_accuracy: 0.8285
Epoch 8/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0261 - accuracy: 0.9562 - val_loss: 0.0756 - val_accuracy: 0.8361
Epoch 9/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 10ms/step - loss: 0.0208 - accuracy: 0.9680 - val_loss: 0.0802 - val_accuracy: 0.8425
Epoch 10/10
236/236 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 0.0177 - accuracy: 0.9760 - val_loss: 0.0877 - val_accuracy: 0.8386
```